# file_get_contents page does not support php

Tags: php, html

I am working with my php new site. Here I want to write an html page using php file write code. In this I used file_get_contents. E.g. see below

```
$page_old.="<table width='1051' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
$page_old.="<tr><td height='50' class='tittle'>Test</td></tr>";
$page_old.="<tr><td class='content'>My content Body</td></tr></table></td></tr>";
$page_old.=file_get_contents('../contents/footer.php');     
fwrite($fp_old,$page_old);
fclose($fp_old);
```

My footer page contains some php code see below

```
<td colspan="4"><a href="../more-products.php?feat1_id=YlX>PdRf" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image49','','../images/Kluz_usa_s_over_18.jpg',1)"><img src="../images/Kluz_usa_s_18.jpg" name="Image49" width="276" height="162" border="0" alt="Universal Laser Systems VersaLASER " title="<?=$test_vra?>" ></a></td>
```

I want to assign the title, alt src value from a php variable. But the result is not correct. E.g. my title tag showing

How I display the actual content from that php variable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) returns a string with the HTML of the provided url.

If you want to use [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite) and [fclose](http://php.net/fclose), you need to open footer.php with fopen.

But your question does not make sense to me. Do you want to overwrite footer.php with `$page_old`? If so, you could use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) and do a `file_put_contents('../contents/footer.php', $page_old);`.

Answer (score 3):

`file_get_contents` will give you the contents of the file as a string, not parse that file as executable code.

The easiest way to do what you want is to turn on output buffering, `include` that PHP file so that it's executed, then append the buffer to your `$page_old` variable.

```
$page_old.="<table width='1051' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
$page_old.="<tr><td height='50' class='tittle'>Test</td></tr>";
$page_old.="<tr><td class='content'>My content Body</td></tr></table></td></tr>";

ob_start();
include('../contents/footer.php');
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$page_old .= $output;

file_put_contents('filename.html', $page_old);
```

Comment: You might want to remove the $page_old.=file_get_contents('../contents/footer.php'); line

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I removed it. I hope I'm reading the question right, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks. But is file_put_contents() support in PHP4 ?

Comment: No, but PHP 4 is not supported anywhere. PHP 5 is more than 7 years old. Nobody should be running PHP 4, it passed end-of-life years ago.